# expected LP_c_float instance instead of tuple in glVertex3fv

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet, opengl-compat

I'm rendering a 3D cube using Python, OpenGL and Pyglet, so I defined `vertices` and `edges` variables in a tuple

```py
vertices = (
    (1, -1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (1, -1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1))

edges = (
    (0, 1),
    (0, 3),
    (0, 4),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 7),
    (6, 3),
    (6, 4),
    (6, 7),
    (5, 1),
    (5, 4),
    (5, 7))
```

after that i defined a function `def Cube()` that *creates* this 3D cube using these coordinates i defined above

```py
def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()
```

so i create a window with `on_draw()` function, that calls the `Cube()` function.

When i run this application on my Linux terminal using the command `python3 main.py` i get the following error

> ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: : expected LP_c_float instance instead of tuple

So i guess the main error of this code is the line `glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])`

I want to know what i need to draw this 3D cube correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter to `glVertex3fv` has to be an array of `float`s.

To solve issue, either use `glVertex3f` and pass 3 separated values:

```py
glVertex3f(vertices[vertex][0], vertices[vertex][1], vertices[vertex][2])
```

Or use pythons [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module to generate an array of `float`s.
The data type of an element is [`c_float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_float) and an [Array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#arrays) can be generated by the `*`-operator:

```py
import ctypes
```

```py
glVertex3fv( (ctypes.c_float * 3)(*vertices[vertex]) )
```